# Logic to display page number in React-Table

Tags: reactjs, pagination, react-table-v7

what would be the logic behind showing page number as below

```
[1]  2   3  ...  184   >
 <   1  [2]  3   4  ...  184   >
 <   1   2  [3]  4   5  ...  184   >
 <   1   2   3  [4]  5   6   ...  184   >
 <   1  ...  3   4  [5]  6    7   ...  184   >
 <   1  ...  4   5  [6]  7    8   ...  184   >
 <   1  ...  5   6  [7]  8    9   ...  184   >
 <   1  ...  6   7  [8]  9    10  ...  184   >
```

I am using React Table which gives me number of pages in array, current pageIndex, total pageCount. It has gotoPage(pageIndex) method which we can use to navigate to perticular page.

can anybody help to achieve such format

Answer (score 0):

I attached a code snippet I used before. It has also goFirst and goLast buttons.
I'm happy if it is helpful for you.

```
<ul className="pagination">
    <li className={`page-item previous ${currentPageIndex === 1 || totalPageCount === 0 ? 'disabled' : ''}`}>
        <button type="button" className="page-link"
            onClick={() => gotoPage(1)}
        >
            <i className="bi bi-chevron-bar-left first"></i>
        </button>
    </li>
    <li className={`page-item previous ${currentPageIndex === 1 || totalPageCount === 0  ? 'disabled' : ''}`}>
        <button type="button" className="page-link"
            onClick={() => gotoPage(currentPageIndex - 1)}
        >
            <i className="previous"></i>
        </button>
    </li>
    {
        totalPageCount < 6 &&
        Array.from(Array(totalPageCount).keys()).map((x, i) =>
            <li className={`page-item ${currentPageIndex === i + 1 ? 'active' : ''}`} key={i}>
                <button type="button" className="page-link"
                    onClick={() => gotoPage(i + 1)}
                >
                    {i + 1}
                </button>
            </li>
        )
    }
    {
        totalPageCount >= 6 && currentPageIndex < 4 &&
        Array.from(Array(4).keys()).map((x, i) =>
            <li className={`page-item ${currentPageIndex === i + 1 ? 'active' : ''}`} key={i}>
                <button type="button" className="page-link"
                    onClick={() => gotoPage(i + 1)}
                >
                    {i + 1}
                </button>
            </li>
        )
    }
    {
        totalPageCount >= 6 && currentPageIndex < 4 &&
        <span className="page-three-dots">
            <i className="bi bi-three-dots"></i>
        </span>
    }
    {
        totalPageCount >= 6 && currentPageIndex >= 4 && currentPageIndex <= totalPageCount - 3 &&
        <span className="page-three-dots">
            <i className="bi bi-three-dots"></i>
        </span>
    }
    {
        totalPageCount >= 6 && currentPageIndex >= 4 && currentPageIndex <= totalPageCount - 3 &&
        <>
            <li className={`page-item`}>
                <button type="button" className="page-link"
                    onClick={() => gotoPage(currentPageIndex - 1)}
                >
                    {currentPageIndex - 1}
                </button>
            </li>
            <li className={`page-item active`}>
                <button type="button" className="page-link"
                    onClick={() => gotoPage(currentPageIndex)}
                >
                    {currentPageIndex}
                </button>
            </li>
            <li className={`page-item`}>
                <button type="button" className="page-link"
                    onClick={() => gotoPage(currentPageIndex + 1)}
                >
                    {currentPageIndex + 1}
                </button>
            </li>
        </>
    }
    {
        totalPageCount >= 6 && currentPageIndex >= 4 && currentPageIndex <= totalPageCount - 3 &&
        <span className="page-three-dots">
            <i className="bi bi-three-dots"></i>
        </span>
    }
    {
        totalPageCount >= 6 && currentPageIndex > totalPageCount - 3 &&
        <span className="page-three-dots">
            <i className="bi bi-three-dots"></i>
        </span>
    }
    {
        totalPageCount >= 6 && currentPageIndex > totalPageCount - 3 &&
        Array.from(Array(4).keys()).map((x, i) =>
            <li className={`page-item ${currentPageIndex === totalPageCount - 3 + i ? 'active' : ''}`} key={i}>
                <button type="button" className="page-link"
                    onClick={() => gotoPage(totalPageCount - 3 + i)}
                >
                    {totalPageCount - 3 + i}
                </button>
            </li>
        )
    }
    <li className={`page-item next ${currentPageIndex === totalPageCount || totalPageCount === 0 ? 'disabled' : ''}`}>
        <button type="button" className="page-link"
            onClick={() => gotoPage(currentPageIndex + 1)}
        >
            <i className="next"></i>
        </button>
    </li>
    <li className={`page-item next ${currentPageIndex === totalPageCount || totalPageCount === 0 ? 'disabled' : ''}`}>
        <button type="button" className="page-link"
            onClick={() => gotoPage(totalPageCount)}
        >
            <i className="bi bi-chevron-bar-right last"></i>
        </button>
    </li>
</ul>
```